# Problem with Wine installation (on Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: 20.04, wine, dpkg

From the "Ubuntu Softwares" folder, I attempted to install Wine.

After clicking on the installation button for Wine, I received this message:

```
Unable to install Wine. 
E: dpkg was interrupted upi must manually run dpkg -- configure a" to correct the problem.
```

Also I gave a try placing the first command on the terminal as indicated by numerous website:

```
yd@yd:~$ dpkg --add-architecture i386
dpkg: error: unable to create new file '/var/lib/dpkg/arch-new': Permission denied
```

I am new to Linux and Ubuntu. What would be the most appropriate course of action to fix this?

thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have enabled broken old repository.

To remove it use commands below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:teejee2008/ppa
```

Then to install wine you really do not need third-party repositories, so you have to disable all such previously added WineHQ repositories by:

```
sudo apt-add-repository -r "deb http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main"
sudo apt-add-repository -r "deb http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main"
sudo apt-add-repository -r "deb http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ groovy main"
sudo apt-add-repository -r "deb http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ hirsute main"

sudo apt-add-repository -r "deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main"
sudo apt-add-repository -r "deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main"
sudo apt-add-repository -r "deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ groovy main"
sudo apt-add-repository -r "deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ hirsute main"
```

and then update package lists, install updates, resume interrupted installations by

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```

And finally install Wine from official repositories by

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

or better install PlayOnLinux (`sudo apt-get install playonlinux`) to install Windows applications using wizards.

---

Note: if you have problems with official default repositories, then re-add them by

```
sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) main restricted universe multiverse"
sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs)-updates main restricted universe multiverse"
sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs)-security main restricted universe multiverse"
sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs)-backports main restricted universe multiverse"
```

and retry above commands.

Comment: AFTER the SUDO APT UPGRADE I received : You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libnss-systemd : Depends: systemd (= 247.3-3ubuntu3.1)
 libpam-systemd : Depends: systemd (= 247.3-3ubuntu3.1)
 systemd : Depends: libsystemd0 (= 247.3-3ubuntu3) but 247.3-3ubuntu3.1 is installed
 systemd-sysv : Depends: systemd (= 247.3-3ubuntu3.1)
 systemd-timesyncd : Depends: systemd (= 247.3-3ubuntu3.1)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: I see you updated your response, Can I proceed over the series of commands?

Comment: Yes, they should help.

Comment: After adding all the repositories with no problem (even the ones placed at the bottom), I placed the command "sudo dpkg --configure -a"  The terminal indicates the same series of ",,,,,error processing package .... (--configure): dependency problems - leaving unconfigured ,,,,,,"

Comment: Please place full output of `grep -r ^deb /etc/apt --include=*.list` and full above error message with executed commands to pastebin. Or more complete - execute all commands from my answer answer and post full output to the pastebin.

Comment: I am figuring out what is a pastebin. I believe I got it. Here is the link: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/cVTHtKsXhs/

Comment: It is now better than it was before. Please run `sudo apt --fix-broken install` as system suggested.

Comment: Ok. Here are the results: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/R89Xn7FCBy/ Should I Proceed with the commands : sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126671/discussion-between-n0rbert-and-yann-monnier).

Answer (score 1):

The installation instruction is documented on [WineHQ website](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu), to install wine on Ubuntu 20.04:

First run (as the message say):

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

then:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
sudo apt-key add winehq.key
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main' 
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

Answer (score -3):

Welcome to Ubuntu! For someone new to Linux and AskUbuntu, that was an astounding question.

I'll run you through absolutely everything. Let's reinstall Wine correctly.

First of all, you will be prompted multiple times to enter Y/press enter or just press enter during installation. Make sure to do that! Also, when you enter a password in the terminal, it may not show your password but it is recording your inputs. Press enter and it will work even if it doesn't show the input!

Please follow my steps. Just copy/paste these into a terminal.

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt update
wget -qO- https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt install software-properties-commonsudo apt-add-repository "deb http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ $(lsb_release -cs) main"
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

Check your Wine status using `wine --version`. If there are no errors, you've made it!

### Resources

- https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-wine-on-ubuntu-20-04/

Comment: Hi Jamie. I followed the commands you placed . here are what I placed and the output:

Comment: Hey! I can't see the output. Could you try again or split it up?

Comment: it was too long , so  I re-edited the primary message

Comment: thanks for the input, i realized i had used a dead server that wine hq doesnt use anymore, this should help, just run the new commands again after reloading the page

Comment: after wget command, i received the following:yd@yd:~$ wget -qO- https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key | sudo apt-key add -
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
OK   Should I continue?

Comment: yes, it will still work.

Comment: yd@yd:~$ sudo apt install software-properties-common
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem. Should I continue?

Comment: do what it says, run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a'

Comment: After launching the command "sudo dpkg --configure -a" ,  the output of the terminal (too long to place here) states series of ",,,,,error processing package .... (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured ,,,,,,"  I believe it would be more adequate to edit a new question before dealing with the Wine issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126669/discussion-between-jamie-and-yann-monnier).

Comment: I hate to be petty but why exactly is my comment so hated? I just want to improve my usefulness but it seems like this was very hated despite me genuinely helping the OP.

Comment: Hey Jamie, I did appreciate your help and your welcome. The process you indicated and our exchanges we had certainly help me (and others) to narrow down the issue. I was used to stack-exchange with Math. I do recall difficult back and forth. At the end of the day , we learn. thx again.