# Unable to install WINE in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, wine, gnome-terminal

I am trying to install the package wine on my ubuntu 20.04 , but it is showing me an error.
I have completely followed all the steps given on https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu , but after giving the command *sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable* it shows the following error :

```
       The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine32:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libwine:i386 (= 5.0-3ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
```

Can anyone solve my problem ??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem with Wine installation (on Ubuntu 20.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1346916/problem-with-wine-installation-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: @user535733 But the instructions he linked do have a listing specific for 20.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The hard way**: read the [FAQ from Wine](https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#How_do_I_solve_dependency_errors_when_trying_to_install_Wine.3F) and do some testing.

**The easier way**: install the packages from Ubuntu repositories.

**The catch**: you have already changed your apt repositories definitions (with the command  *'sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https:// dl.winehq.org/ wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main'*).

To unroll these changes, you can find a good reference [here](https://www.linuxfordevices.com/tutorials/ubuntu/remove-an-apt-repository-ubuntu)

When you are done with that, you will use Ubuntu repositories.

And this should install Wine:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install wine
```