# Ubuntu20.04 failed to install wine due to libc6 dependency issues

Tags: 20.04, wine, dependencies

(I'm Chinese and I use translator to write this)

I use ubuntu 20.04

I refer to https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu tutorial install wine.

It reported an error when I used the apt install command:

`sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable`

winehq-stable depends on wine-stable

wine-stable depends on libc6>=2.34 but ubuntu20.04 only provide libc6=2.31

I tried to change to a different wine version but it didn't work

I tried to [Unable to install WINE in ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1349571/unable-to-install-wine-in-ubuntu-20-04) but it still didn't work